# Calculate difference between two dates in mysql to show years and months

Tags: mysql, date

How can I calculate difference between two dates ( current date and a date stored in database ) in mysql query to give result in years and months.

Suppose there are two dates - `2014-01-01`  and `2015-12-28` then I want the result to be displayed as `1.11 years`. how can I do that ?

Right now I'm using `round(datediff(curdate(),e.joined_date)/365` which gives me value in years.

Please help.

Comment: whay not use `timestampdiff` function ?

Comment: 1.11 years would be confusing though. I guess the '11' stands for 11 months, but when I read 1.11 I'd think of it as 1 year and about a tenth of a year. Maybe '1 year 11 months' would be better?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty - will it give result similar what I have asked in my question as 1.11 Years in one column ?

Comment: @igorshmigor - yes you are right. it is 1 year and 11 months. But how can I do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `TIMESTAMPDIFF` like this

```
SELECT CONCAT(TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, '2014-06-01', '2015-08-01'), '.', TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, '2014-06-01', '2015-08-01')-(TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, '2014-06-01', '2015-08-01') * 12)) AS diff
```